# How to hide an account on KDE login screen?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, login, kde

I am running a CentOS 7 virtual machine on my laptop and I'm using KDE (version 4.14.8). That VM serves as an Ansible control tower, from which my Ansible descriptions are applied to the other (headless) VMs that I use on the same laptop.

My problem is that the graphical login screen shows my account as well as the account `ansible`. I thought system accounts would not show up in that list so I created `ansible` as a system account. But here is an excerpt from my `/etc/passwd` file:

```
hg:x:1002:1002:Mercurial SCM:/home/hg:/bin/bash
saned:x:986:980:SANE scanner daemon user:/usr/share/sane:/sbin/nologin
backupscript:x:1003:1004:Data backup script:/home/backupscript:/sbin/nologin
ansible:x:985:979::/home/ansible:/bin/bash
```

As can be seen, `hg` is a user account, but it does not show up in the login screen, which means to me that the user account vs system account distinction is not the element that determines whether an account is shown in the login screen or not.

How can I hide an account on the login screen?

Comment: Is there a password defined for that `ansible` user?

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a password to that account.

Comment: Then remove it. With the proper setup you can `su` to it from you own account when needed.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't though of that. But the account still shows up and clicking it logged me directly into a Gnome desktop.

Answer (score 2):

In Kubuntu, you can add line **HideUsers=ansible** in **/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf** Under **[Users]** section.

Automated:

```sh
(
  username=ansible
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/sddm.conf.d
  echo "[Users]" | sudo tee /etc/sddm.conf.d/hide_${username}.conf
  echo "HideUsers=$username" | sudo tee -a /etc/sddm.conf.d/hide_${username}.conf
)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but it's quite similar to the previous suggestion I had received. I have no 'sddm' file or folder in `/etc/`.

Comment: Works on fedora 36 kde

Answer (score 1):

To hide the user account, you can add **HideUsers=ansible** in /etc/sddm.conf under the [User] session.

Comment: I have done what you suggested, to no avail. The file did not exist and I created it. But the user still shows up on the account list from which I want to remove it. A `yum list sddm` reveals that sddm is not installed, which probably explains why the conf file is not taken into account.

Comment: I think you first need to find out what Desktop manager you are using. Those directives was for sddm, but it seems it is not the one your are currently using. You can see the content of **/etc/X11/default-display-manager** to find that. After that you have to search for appropriate configuration for that desktop manager.

Answer (score 1):

As of KDE 5, [SDDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Desktop_Display_Manager) is the default login manager. Since you’re running KDE 4, I expect your system uses [KDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager) instead. The KDM Handbook is no longer online, but the Wayback Machine has come to the rescue!

[Chapter 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20150612052414/https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kde-workspace/kdm/configuring-kdm.html) says you can do what you need through System Settings → Login Manager, but it doesn’t give specifics:

> #### Users
>
> From here you can change the way users are represented in the login window.
>
> Independently of the users you specify by name, you can use the System UIDs to specify a range of valid UIDs that are shown in the list. By default user id's under 1000, which are often system or daemon users, and user id's over 30000, are not shown.

Or [Chapter 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730144014/http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kdm/kdm-files.html) says you could edit `kdmrc`:

> **ShowUsers**
>
> This option controls which users will be shown in the user view (**UserList**) and/or offered for autocompletion (**UserCompletion**). If it is `Selected`, **SelectedUsers** contains the final list of users. If it is `NotHidden`, the initial user list contains all users found on the system. Users contained in **HiddenUsers** are removed from the list, just like all users with a UID greater than specified in **MaxShowUID** and users with a non-zero UID less than specified in **MinShowUID**. Items in **SelectedUsers** and **HiddenUsers** which are prefixed with `@` represent all users in the user group named by that item. Finally, the user list will be sorted alphabetically, if **SortUsers** is enabled.
>
> The default is “NotHidden”.

(A quick search suggests this file should be located at `/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc`.)

---

What’s interesting is that your `/etc/passwd` shows that `ansible` has a UID of 985… so it should already be hidden by default. Either of the above configuration options might let you see that this default has been overridden somehow.

If all else fails, you can manually change the user `ansible` to have some other UID and see if that fixes the problem.

First, find an unused UID. This command will list all the *used* ones:

```
$ awk -F: '$0=$3 "\t"$1' /etc/passwd | sort -g
```

Then, assuming you’ve found that 39001 is available, change the UID like so:

```
$ sudo usermod -u 39001 ansible
```

Note that any files that `ansible` owns will only have their ownership updated *if they are in `ansible`’s home directory* (`/home/ansible` according to your `/etc/passwd`). Anything else that `ansible` owns will need to be `chown`’d manually.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and researched answer. I hope it'll be useful to others. I no longer have the issue, to my baffling, as I haven't done anything I can recall to successfully hide user Ansible. What's more, I just checked, and that user's UID is now… 1004. I have no existing `kdmrc` file.